# Salsa20 using Crypto++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the salsa20 code in the crypto++ Library. ( http://www.cryptopp.com/) to communicate between two programs.

Both programs use the same code which follows

```
std::string salsaDo(std::string key, std::string msg, byte iv[STREAM_IV_LENGTH]) {

    //Set up byte arrays for proccess
    byte *plaintextBytes = (byte *)msg.c_str();
    byte *ciphertextBytes = new byte[msg.length()];
    byte *reversetextBytes = new byte[msg.length()];

    //Set up key array
    byte* keyBytes = (byte *)key.substr(0, STREAM_KEY_LENGTH).c_str();

    //Peform encryption method
    Salsa20::Encryption salsa;
    salsa.SetKeyWithIV(keyBytes, STREAM_KEY_LENGTH, iv);
    salsa.ProcessData(ciphertextBytes, plaintextBytes, msg.length());

    salsa.SetKeyWithIV(keyBytes, STREAM_KEY_LENGTH, iv);
    salsa.ProcessData(reversetextBytes, ciphertextBytes, msg.length());

    std::string ivStr((char*)iv, STREAM_IV_LENGTH);

    std::cout << "____\nK:" << key.c_str();
    std::cout << "\nI:" << ivStr.c_str();
    std::cout << "\nM:" << msg.c_str();
    std::cout << "\nE:" << std::string((const char *)ciphertextBytes, msg.length()).c_str();
    std::cout << "\nR:" << std::string((const char *)reversetextBytes, msg.length()).c_str();
    std::cout << "\n____\n";

    //return  msg;

    //return string 
    return std::string((const char *)ciphertextBytes, msg.length());

}
```

An image from the programs is at http://s21.postimg.org/wgfmkjcn9/encrypt.png

Explanation:

- Step1 : plain text is encrypted (server-M to server-E)
- Step2 : encrypted text is decrypted (Server-E to server-R and client-M to client-E.) These two should give the same result but don't
- Step3 : client-E is run through again to check that it equals the msg the server sent.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited for Stack Overflow since this deals with the actual programming aspect of implementing a cryptographic library. Regardless, I'm not really sure what exactly you are asking, OP.

Comment: So the problem is that you're getting gibberish?

Comment: The problem is the client E does not equal the server M. And I was not sure which one to post it on either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code.

1. This line technically invokes Undefined Behavior:

   ```
   byte* keyBytes = (byte *)key.substr(0, STREAM_KEY_LENGTH).c_str();
   ```

   In this case, the `substr()` call returns a temporary `std::string` object containing the substring.  The lifetime of this temporary `std::string` extends through the evaluation of the entire line (the full expression).  The lifetime of the C string returned by `std::string::c_str()` is the same as the `std::string`, except that it is invalidated by a mutating operation.  Thus, in this full expression, `keyBytes` is likely an invalid pointer once the line has executed.

   You can fix the problem by overwriting `key` to the desired substring.  In this case, assigning to `key` ensures that the lifetime is extended through where it is used:

   ```
   key = key.substr(0, STREAM_KEY_LENGTH);
   const byte* keyBytes = static_cast<const byte*>(key.c_str());
   ```
2. This `salsaDo()` function leaks memory.  The byte arrays created by:

   ```
   byte *ciphertextBytes = new byte[msg.length()];
   byte *reversetextBytes = new byte[msg.length()];
   ```

   .. are not freed.  Consider using a `std::unique_ptr<byte[]>`:

   ```
   std::unique_ptr<byte[]> ciphertextBytes(new byte[msg.length()]);
   std::unique_ptr<byte[]> reversetextBytes(new byte[msg.length()]);
   ```
3. C++ does not technically support passing arrays to functions.  The parameter `byte iv[STREAM_IV_LENGTH]` is actually treated as if you had written `byte* iv` instead.

   You could pass a reference to the array.  Also, for const-correctness, you should mark the initialization vector bytes `const`:

   ```
   std::string salsaDo(std::string key, std::string msg, const byte (&iv)[STREAM_IV_LENGTH])
   {
       //...
   }
   ```
4. I wouldn't use a `std::string` to store the key, or really any array of bytes such as the returned encrypted bytes.  Consider using a `std::unique_ptr<byte[]>` or `std::shared_ptr<byte[]>`, or passing a reference to a const array, or passing a pointer and length (e.g. `const byte* key` and `size_t keyLength`).

Comment: Client M is equal to the server E as far as I can tell.  (and removing the encryption code does pass the msg correctly)

Comment: @Catprog: Ah, yes, you are right that Client M = Server E.  Can you try fixing the Undefined Behavior?

Comment: That was indeed the problem. The programs are now talking again.